# Self written eclipse plugin works for Luna, but not for Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, manifest.mf

I developed an plugin in

- *Eclipse Standard/SDK*
- *Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)*
- *Build id: 20140925-1800*

and it works fine. I could install it via my *feature project* to this eclipse version (Luna). But now I try to install the same plugin for

- *Android Developer Tools*
- *Eclipse Platform Juno*
- *Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7*
- *Build id: M20130204-1200*

and it does not work. I just found a similiar problem on stack**overflow**, but not a solution ... [Eclipse plugin developed under Helios doesn't show in Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876569/eclipse-plugin-developed-under-helios-doesnt-show-in-juno) .

Does anyone have an idea?

**Some notes:**

- I haven't got any warnings/errors or something like this while installation.
- In "plugins\AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin_1.0.0.201503170126" exists my plugin
- In "\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info" is "AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin,1.0.0.201503170126,plugins/AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin_1.0.0.201503170126/,4,false" the first entry
- I see the plugin in eclipse Juno, but the menu-entry "Enable AAL Validator Builder" is not available in this one :/

I guess the installation was successful, but something is wrong in my manifest file.... or is it a problem of my eclipse Juno version?

**Here are some files of my plugin:**

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-SymbolicName: AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/jericho-html-3.3.jar,
 .
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="validationBuilder"
         name="AAL Validation Builder"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders">
      <builder
            hasNature="true">
         <run
               class="aal.hfu.html_parser.eclipse.plugin.ValidationBuilder">
                <parameter name="optimize" value="true" />
                <parameter name="comment" value="Builder comment" />
         </run>
      </builder>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="nature"
         name="AAL Validation Nature"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.natures">
      <runtime>
         <run
               class="aal.hfu.html_parser.eclipse.plugin.Nature">
         </run>
      </runtime>
      <builder
            id="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.validationBuilder">
      </builder>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="AAL Validator Nature commands"
            id="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.nature.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Toggle AAL Validator Nature"
            defaultHandler="aal.hfu.html_parser.eclipse.plugin.AddRemoveNatureHandler"
            categoryId="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.nature.category"
            id="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.addRemoveNature">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.projectConfigure?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.addRemoveNature"
               label="Disable AAL Validator Builder"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="selection">
                  <count
                        value="1">
                  </count>
                  <iterate>
                     <adapt
                           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                        <test
                              value="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.nature"
                              property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature">
                        </test>
                     </adapt>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
         <command
               commandId="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.addRemoveNature"
               label="Enable AAL Validator Builder"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="selection">
                  <count
                        value="1">
                  </count>
                  <iterate>
                     <adapt
                           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                        <not>
                           <test
                                 value="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin.nature"
                                 property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature">
                           </test>
                        </not>
                     </adapt>
                  </iterate>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="AalProblem"
         name="AAL Problem"
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
      <super
            type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
      </super>
      <persistent
            value="false">
      </persistent>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

build.properties

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               lib/jericho-html-3.3.jar,\
               lib/
```

**Here are some files of my plugin feature:**

feature.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feature
      id="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin_Feature"
      label="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin_Feature"
      version="1.0.0.qualifier"
      provider-name="HFU">

   <description url="http://www.example.com/description">
      This validator is a part of the master thesis by xyz.
   </description>

   <copyright url="http://www.example.com/copyright">
      [Enter Copyright Description here.]
   </copyright>

   <license url="http://www.example.com/license">
      Open Source
   </license>

   <requires>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
      <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
   </requires>

   <plugin
         id="AAL_Validator_Eclipse_Plugin"
         download-size="192"
         install-size="185"
         version="1.0.0.qualifier"/>

</feature>
```

build.properties

```
bin.includes = feature.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You plug in using java 8 as minimal execution environment. Juno doesn't support java 8. Probably change the minimal execution environment. in manifest.Mf file overview tab then install it to your juno. It would work.